# How to compile a stored procedure from C#?

Tags: c#, oracle

I want design a stored procedure / function creator program where user can create stored
procedure and function. I want to compile the sp or function from my C# program. If any bug is found I want to show to the user. How it can be done? Same functionality is available in the Toad or SQL Navigator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a c# command object that implements IDbCommand then you can call the .Prepare() method on it to precompile the SP and get any errors back to feed back to the user:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.prepare(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a working example at hand, but you can run the DDL quite easy with `execute immediate`.

If your DDL is > 32K and you're on 11g, simply use a clob to store the DDL. Pain begins w/ > 32 K and 10g or below. There you'd have to use DBMS_SQL.parse and pass your DDL as an Array.

In order to show compilation errors you could first catch any exceptions thrown when running the DDL. Then query ´ALL_ERRORS´ to find the detailed compiler messages.